# Is there a way to ignore the watermark when using Ghostscript to convert PDF to TIFF

Tags: pdf, tiff, ghostscript

I'm using gs9.10 and have successfully converted my PDF to TIFF using this command line:

```
gswin64c -dNOPAUSE -q -r300x300 -sDEVICE=tifflzw \
         -dBATCH -sCompression=lzw -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=5 \
         -sOutputFile=TEST.TIFF \
          TEST.PDF
```

However, I don't want the TIFF to have the watermark that is on every page of the PDF. Is there an option to ignore the watermark layer when writing out to a TIFF?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, this sounds suspiciously like trying to circumvent copyright. Obviously I can't tell since I haven't seen your original PDF file but watermarks are often applied to 'demo' or paid-for PDF files.

In any event, without seeing the file its impossible to say whether a watermark can be removed, because it depends on how the watermark has been applied, there are at least 3 different ways that I can think of off-hand and 2 of those I could eliminate the watermark later. There is unlikely to be a 'watermark layer' in the PDF file.

If you post a URL to the original PDF file I can look at it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share the PDF as we're on contract not to disclose. I am not trying to circumvent copyright. The original PDF needs to be parsed to text for loading to database. The PDF has an embedded font issue causing incorrect text extraction. I'm attempting to convert the PDF to Tiff and then use an OCR tool to create a searchable PDF and then extracting the text. The watermark is not a copyright, it's a diagonal Non-negotiable message which causes text extraction issues so want to remove it before extraction. Any ideas how to do this would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I take that back, it would be a copyright watermark but have permission to extract the text.

Comment: Without seeing the file, there's really very little I can offer. The watermark may be applied as an annotation, in which case you could choose not to render the annotation. If not then it may be applied as text in the body of the document, in which case it could be removed by decompressing the data stream and replacing with white space. Or it may be done by writing vector or graphical data into the content stream in which case it would be possible but more difficult to pull the same trick. There's really no way to tell without looking at the file. Or at least a similar one.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just about text extraction, this command should do it:

```
 pdftotext \
   -layout \
    input.pdf
    output.txt
```

1. Now, if your "watermark" is no text, but some sort of image or vector graphic, it will not be part of your output.txt
2. Now, if your "watermark" indeed is also text, that watermark string will also appear in your output text for each page. It should be easy to remove that string from the text (and replace it by nothing if unwanted).
3. If your "watermark" text appears as gobble-di-gook in output.txt, then the font type ("Type 3"?) or font encoding ("custom"?) used for the watermark text does not allow for easy text extraction, or a valid "ToUnicode" map is missing for the font used.
4. If your main text did not extract successfully from the PDF, and if your main text is "gobble-di-gook", it very likely won't extract any better when removing the "watermark" from the original PDF file before applying `pdftotext` either...

Comment: Thanks. I have a pdf file (http://samples.jblearning.com/9781284106008/TsuiTOCwithPreface.pdf) with watermarked text. I use the same `pdftotext -layout` command to extract the text, it extracts the watermarked text too and that is split all over the place. How could I only extract the text in the front without the watermarked text?